# No Protocol Specified. Error: Can't open display. How do I resolve this?

Tags: linux, terminal, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-os-flex

I have installed Chrome OS Flex on my PC, which runs great, and I have turned on and installed Linux via the Developer menu in Settings.

The problem is that I cannot run installed Linux applications. When I open them via the Linux apps folder in the "start menu", they just appear and seem to be loading forever.

If I try to run the applications via Terminal:

`sudo sh ./rider.sh`

they just show an error that says:

```
jase@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Downloads/JetBrains Rider-2023.1.2/bin$ sudo sh ./rider.sh
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
And it doesn't matter which linux app I try to run, they all display the same erorr.
```

How can this be resolved?

I've spent a day or two researching this error and not a single thing I've tried has resolved the issue. I can't even remember everything I've tried.

One of the things suggested was: `xhost +`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Does this occur with other X11 programs or just this one? Specifically, does this occur with programs that are being run *without* sudo? (Why does JetBrains need sudo, anyway?)

Comment: @user1686 It happens with or without sudo. Even after installing Wine and Wine32 I can't even get anything running on wine (same errors). Also, winecfg crashes the terminal.